# Drupal 7 Solr 4 $query group by

Tags: solr, drupal-7

I'm beginner in Drupal 7 et Solr 4. I have $query and I want to do a group by category.
How can I add 'group by' as a parameter to $query (DrupalSolrQueryInterface) ??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solve my problem. In the view of Apache Solr, I enter the parameter and and add the field of group by. That's all.